# Java Jersey/Jackson: return dynamic JSON properties

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey

We use jackson to deserialize java objects (DTO's) towards JSON for our endpoints. This works well. However, I have a bit on an odd question.

Let's say we have an object User, and we have metadata attached to this user. The metadata can really be anything the client can think of, so this is very dynamic.

The client can make a request, to retrieve certain metadata properties of a certain user. Let's say the client wants to have the following metadata properties: age and  favouriteTree (because some people have one, right? the point is, metadata can be anything, and we don't know this beforehand).

I would like to return the following JSON:

```
{
    "userId" : 1,
    "age" : 22,
    "favouriteTree" : "Maple Tree"
}
```

I could simply have a Java POJO with an int userId, int age, and a String favouriteTree in it. This way, we can let Jackson deserialize it towards JSON and all is good.

However, the next time the client uses the same endpoint, it might request different properties, such as: colorEyes and favouriteFood, in which case I'd want to return:

```
{
    "userId" : 1,
    "colorEyes" : "blue",
    "favouriteFood" : "Pizza"
}
```

Now I would need another Java POJO for just those kind of metadata as well to deserialize it the way we normally do. But since the metadata can be anything, we can't do that, because we don't want to keep adding POJO's towards our code as different customers will have different needs.

Is there a generic kind of way to do this in Java?

Edit:

I know I could do something like:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "metadata": [{
            "key": "colorEyes",
            "value": "blue"
        },
        {
            "key": "favouriteFood",
            "value": "Pizza"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: So you want to return different things and you never know what you're returning?

Comment: I know what I'll be returning based on the request of the user, but the properties are dynamic, so I can't use regualar POJO's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the endpoint return a `JsonNode`, which would allow you to return any kind of json. If you have some base DTO, you could map it to `JsonNode`, then include any dynamic parameters there.

Code snippet example:

```
JsonNode jn = // map some BaseDTO to JsonNode
ObjectNode on = (ObjectNode)jn; // We need to cast to ObjectNode for mutation
on.put("attribute", whateverValue);

return on;
```

Comment: I've read upon this and I think I can use this. Found some more info here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonnode.html

I'm going to play with it, and let you know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL is ideal for your use case.

I understand that it is not the technology stack you are asking about, but it does exactly what you want. The client will define the data they want from the service and only the requested data will be returned.

And your service will be less complicated and easier to maintain/extend than doing it yourself by manipulating json.

Check this link for an intro: https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/

Comment: This is actually very interesting, but would require some rework of our current architecture. I'm going to dive into this though, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @RensGroenveld happy to help, we use it in a couple of projects and it's very cool

Comment: @mart It's "use the right tool for the right job", not "use the cool tool for the right job". Don't get too enamored with a tech, there's nothing cool about changing your whole stack to solve a simple problem, just because you want to use the latest hype tech.

Comment: @Kayaman I appreciate the input and you are correct. Is graphql not the right tool for this use case in your opinion? - besides the changing the stack thing :) They have the context of their application and they know if it is worth the change.

Comment: @mart of course not. It violates the KISS principle by requiring the whole stack to be changed. There are most likely good uses for GraphQL, but you shouldn't try to shoehorn it everywhere just because you like it. My solution is far simpler, and most likely acceptable. You're overengineering.

Comment: @Kayaman sure. And your solution is more simple indeed. Good job. But last thing I ll say on it. Didn't say use it because it is cool, I said it fits the use case imo. Finding things cool and fun is the reason I do this job. And again, I don't have context on their use case. I offered suggestion, they know better

Comment: @mart I know, and I recognize the coolness factor. It's just that you get the "Hey, this could be solved with GraphQL/Microservices/NoSQL/insert tech here" effect where you have a solution in want of a problem, and you overestimate the usefulness of the tech. I know it makes development more exciting when you have new "toys" to tinker with, but for efficient SW development you really need to stick to what you need. But that comes later when you don't get satisfaction from writing code anymore (unfortunately).

Comment: @mart np. And I will be reading that GraphQL link you gave too.

Answer (score -1):

For the case you said, you can completely wrap the example you gave above, just like using map to accept the request data, and then converting the map to json format, you can use

```
<dependency here. >
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.9</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
```

The ObjectMapper tool class in this jar to convert the map to json，like this

```
public static String object2Json(Object o){
        try{
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
        }catch (Exception e){
            log.warn("json serialize fail:", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, how would I be filling the object that I pass along with different kind of properties?

Comment: This tool class also has a method to convert json format data into any type of object you want. I think you can read the request parameter from the request, then convert it to map, perform the corresponding processing and then convert. Return for json

Comment: like this method
public static <T> T json2Object(String json, Class<T> type){
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("json deserialize fail:", e);
            return null;
        }

    }

Comment: Because the Java language is object-oriented, if you need a variety of object-receiving types, either use a map-like way to store, or you can extract the public properties of many objects as parent classes, and separate inheritance of different properties.

Comment: I understand that in large projects, if the project involves interaction between multi-language systems, there may be a type conversion problem on the java side. If there is no strict restriction, the map can be used, but for the specification, we generally unify the interface parameters. Format, or use if to determine for each different object type